# NavigationItem TitleView constraint not working

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uinavigationbar, swift4.2, titleview

I want to create a search bar using UITextField. I tried to set NavigationItem's TitleView to the textfield and set corresponding constraints. But the textfield remain very short in the center of the navigation bar. How to make the textfield fill the whole navigation bar? Here is my code:

```
cancelbtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(CourseTableViewController.searchCancelled))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelbtn

let searchField = UITextField()
searchField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
searchField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchField
self.navigationItem.titleView!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: cancelbtn.width)
self.navigationItem.titleView!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width - cancelbtn.width)
```

And is how it looks rn:
[UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No7iY.png)

Comment: You may want to look into using UISearchController.

Comment: I want to use UITextField because it has features like textFieldShouldReturn, which is essential for my app. Is there anyway to grow the text field to occupy the whole navigation bar except the cancel button on the left?

Comment: UISearchController has a UISearchBar. UISearchBarDelegate has most of the same methods as UITextFieldDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Instead of using the titleView, I put the textfield in the right barButtonItem and set its width to view.frame.size.width. This gives me a textfield that occupy the whole navigation. I attached the code here incase someone also wants to do it.

```
searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
searchBar.placeholder = "Course name"
searchBar.delegate = self
cancelbtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(CourseTableViewController.searchCancelled))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelbtn

searchTextField = UITextField()
searchTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
searchTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width - cancelbtn.width)
searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchTextField)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.width = view.frame.size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read Apple guidelines about that. From iOS11 you should install searchBar into navigationItem. Try to use this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate {

var searchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self

    // Customisation 
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .black
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}

}
```

Comment: I want to implement a Quora-style search bar. The button on the left allow user return to previous view and right of the button is a textfield which allows user to search.The search controller cannot integrate the return button.